# Difficulties with changing localization

Tags: android, localization

In my application, I want to support multiple languages. I found a source with good implementations. Here's what I have at the moment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String countryCode = data.getStringExtra(CountrycodeActivity.RESULT_CONTRYCODE);
            String lang = "en";
            switch (countryCode) {
                case "English":
                    lang = "en";
                    break;
                case "Deutsch":

                    break;
                case "Русский":
                    lang = "ru";
                    break;
                case "Español":

                    break;


            }
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your native language is:" + countryCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            changeLang(lang);
        }
    }

    private void changeLang(String lang) {
        if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            return;
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
        saveLocale(lang);
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
        config.locale = myLocale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    }

    private void saveLocale(String lang) {
        String langPref = "Language";
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(langPref, lang);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

I want to implement two things: changing the language while the application is running, and saving the language for initialization on subsequent launches.Now my language changes on the fly, when I select the right language from the list, but then I can not figure out how to make the language load the next time I launch the application, and the whole program was in the language I needed. I tried to call changing method from my `onCreate()` method, but my application went in cycles. So I don't how to it. Here my calling the changing method at `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sp = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0);
        String local = sp.getString("def_loc", "");
        changeLang(local);
        setContentView(activity_login);
```

Answer (score 0):

This library should help you.

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity

Override method `attachBaseContext` in Activity

```
    public Context attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        String loc = getSharedPreferences("def_loc", 0).getString("Language","" );
        Locale locale = new Locale(loc);
        Configuration config = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            LocaleList localeList = new LocaleList(locale);
            LocaleList.setDefault(localeList);
            config.setLocales(localeList);
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
            Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            config.setLocale(locale);
            return context.createConfigurationContext(config);
        } else {
            return context;
        }
    }
```

Did't tested code, but hope it should help

Comment: thank you, but the following library won't solve my problem, it is another way of solving my task, maybe you know how I have to improve my code?

Comment: Check from line 60.

https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity/blob/master/localizationActivity/src/main/java/com/akexorcist/localizationactivity/core/LocalizationActivityDelegate.java

Comment: You need to set locale in configuaration when start activity. Just learn this class which i sent and try to understand logic

Comment: I tried to set locale when my activity starts, but my activity go in cycle